# Вопрос по библиотеке Glide

Tags: android, recyclerview, glide

Нашел хороший материал по создании галереи на основе библиотеки `Glide`.
В плане кода вроде все понятно, но вот почему то когда вставляю в файл XML вот такую вот строчку кода `<info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout` у меня абсолютно все стает красное.
Пишет:

> Class referenced in the layout file
> info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout was not found in the
> project on the libraries.

Я вообще не понимаю почему у меня такое выдает, java класс SquareLayout у меня есть, библиотека подключена. Кто может объяснить, что не так то? И вот эта строка `info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout` я не совсем понимаю почему так пишут? Это обращение к классу в этой библиотеки или что?

```
<info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout>
```

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. Используемый вами класс - из какой-то либы, которая 5 лет не обновлялась и, вроде, её ещё и очень сложно подключить. Скорее всего вам надо выкинуть SquareLayout и как-то по другому решать вашу задачу. Glide в вопросе, кажется, вообще не при чём.

Comment: Этот класс SquareLayout я написал, в нем создается квадрат с нужными мне параметрами, потом в этот квадрат будет помещаться картинка в галереи. По идеи info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout - это путь к этому классу, но я что-то не уверен в этом. Поэтому спросил думал может кто-то сможет обьяснить.

Answer (score 0):

Все разобрался, как я и думал info.androidhive.glide.helper.SquareLayout - это путь к java файлу.